# Makefiles: Is there are a general way to show which line from makefile is causing the error?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm trying to find a line from the makefile, and have the following output when I run `make clean`:

```
rm -f     ../../lib/i386/ ../../lib/i386/
rm: cannot remove `../../lib/i386/': Is a directory
```

The above first line is the command. The second is the error. I know how to fix the error, but I don't know where the first line is being called.

Note: The problem is compounded because I don't exactly know which makefile this is coming from. We have several `include` statements that traverse several makefiles. For instance...

```
include make_example.inc
```

make_example.inc contains:

```
include make_example_example.inc
```

EDIT: I'm looking for a built in way to show which line from which makefile error. Is there anything like this built into makefiles or a tool that can do this? Using find and grep can take lots of time depending on the situation. The above is just an example.

Comment: `remake` or `make -d` will probably give you a clue

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a new-enough version of GNU make, you can use the `--trace` flag.

Answer (score 1):

in the root of your source directory, run:

`find . -name "make*" | xargs grep -n "../../lib/i386"`

(*Assumes all your makefiles start with "make" and that you are on a unix-like OS)

Based on the below comment, also try:

`find . -name "make*" | xargs grep -n "rm -f"`

Comment: it also assumes the directory appears verbatim, but it could be coming from something like `$(LIBDIR)/$(TARGET)`. Searching for `rm` might be a better bet, but some makefiles use `$(RM)` or `$(RM_F)` so even that could be unreliable.

Comment: I provided that as an example, sorry. I guess there is no general way to turn on which line from which makefile.